How can I add a different email client as a default app on Windows 10?
I ask because right now, only the basic "Email" app and some browsers are available but there's only the option to look for more apps on the Windows store. I want to use Mailspring as my default app for emails. How would I go about doing this, considering I can't find it in the settings?


Download the Mailspring (or Thunderbird, or other email client installer) using a browser (such as MS Windows' Edge).
Check the downloaded file at VirusTotal for safety.
Double-click the installer file that you downloaded, and follow directions.
After installation completes, and you decide to keep that mail client, open Windows Settings, select Default apps, and select the email client.



I already installed it, that's why I'm asking

Are you stating that you cannot use Settings to set Default apps?? Is this a corporate PC, where that is forbidden by GPO???

No?? It's just that Mailspring doesn't appear as a default app option there. I wouldn't ask how to set Mailspring as a default app if I already had the ability to do so.

Odd... could be Mailspring does not register itself as a mail client in Windows. You sued the standard Mailspring installer? Did you do so as a different user (e.g., Administrator)? On the other hand, can you install Thunderbird, and see if it shows in the list of clients?

I don't recall if I used the default installer or just imported the files from my old computer... if the latter, though, reinstalling has not fixed the issue. Also, I just installed Thunderbird and it does show up on the list.

@AndreM962, since T'bird does show correctly, and M'sping, not, this appears to be a defect in that installer. Though you could manually find Registry entries made by T'bird (i.e., uninstall, use Nirsoft's RegistryChangesView to make snapshot, reinstall and use that tool to diff Registry), do you want to accommodate a deficient installer?

To be honest, the whole reason I asked this question was because I was hoping to receive a step-by-step on how to manually make the necessary changes to the Registry in order for Mailspring to appear as a Default app option or to make it become the default app forcibly if necessary. Although I am seriously considering switching to Thunderbird now, since it has features that Mailspring lacks at the moment...
